# complete always gets called in jquery animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

The complete callback in the jquery animation function always gets called.
I'm looking for a way to pause the animation then start back up or just restart it all together. And not call complete unless it truly completes.

```
<div id="outerdiv" style="width:500px">
     <div id="innerdiv" style="width:0px;></div>
</div>
<input value="stop" id="btnstop" type="submit" />
```

```
$('#innerdiv').animate({ width: "100%" }, { 
    queue: false, 
    duration: 90000, 
    complete: function () { /* always hits after 90 secs even when stop is called.  */ } });

$('#btnstop').click(function(){
    $('#innerdiv').stop();
});
```

Comment: thank you but I was wrong on my statement.  the call to the complete statement was being called from a different browser than the one I thought I was working in. 

I think my comment should be down graded.  its not true.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `done` , `fail` `promise` object within `.animate()`

```js
var innerDiv = $("#innerdiv");

function startStop(duration, props) {
  return innerDiv.animate({
    width: props
  }, {
    queue: false,
    duration: duration,
    done: function(promise) {
      // do stuff when animation completed
      console.log("done", promise, duration, props);
      alert("complete")
    },
    fail: function(promise) {
      // continue original `duration` set 
      // minus animation `duration` completed
      $(this).data("d", promise.opts.duration - ($.now() - promise.startTime));
      console.log("stopped"
                 , promise 
                 , promise.opts.duration
                 , this.style.width)
    }
  });

}

$("#btnstop").click(function() {
  innerDiv.stop(true, false);
});

$("#btnstart").click(function() {
  var duration = innerDiv.data("d") || 9000;
  startStop(duration, "100%")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="outerdiv" style="width:500px">
  <div id="innerdiv" style="width:0px;height:50px;border:1px solid blue;"></div>
</div>
<input value="stop" id="btnstop" type="button" />
<input value="start" id="btnstart" type="button" />
```

Comment: thank you but I was wrong on my statement.  the call to the complete statement was being called from a different browser than the one I thought I was working in. 

I think my comment should be down graded.  its not true.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing speechmark on your innerdiv style parameter.

I've set up a fiddle to demonstrate play, pause & reset at https://jsfiddle.net/k7wmzyn8/3/

```
var div = $('#innerdiv');

$('#play').on('click', function(){
    div.animate({ width: "100%" }, { 
        duration: 5000,
        queue: false,
        complete: function() { 
            alert('complete called');
        } 
    });
})

$('#pause').on('click', function(){
    div.stop();
})

$('#reset').on('click', function(){
    div.css('width', '0');
})
```